# Custom divider - counter row number in Result Set

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-order-by, row-number

I have an important issue. I will explain my scenario.

I'm building an stored procedure that receives a parameter called '@rowcountdivider' and it's INTEGER.

My Result Set has data like this:

```
iStore  |  vCode  | iQty
----------------------------
9       |  00001  |   1
9       |  00001  |   1
9       |  00001  |   1
9       |  00001  |   1
9       |  00001  |   1
9       |  00002  |   1
9       |  00003  |   1
9       |  00003  |   1
9       |  00003  |   1
```

Now, i need 'sum-count' this rows with my input parameter (EXAMPLE: @rowcountdivider = 4). Something like this:

```
iStore  |  vCode  | iQty  |  MasterCounter
-------------------------------------------
9       |  00001  |   1   |    1
9       |  00001  |   1   |    1
9       |  00001  |   1   |    1
9       |  00001  |   1   |    1 -- Their row number sum '@rowcountdivider' value (4) and MasterCounter increments in 1
9       |  00001  |   1   |    2
9       |  00002  |   1   |    2
9       |  00003  |   1   |    2
9       |  00003  |   1   |    2 -- Their row number sum the '@rowcountdivider' value (4) and MasterCounter increments in 1
9       |  00003  |   1   |    3 -- Their row number don't sum '@rowcountdivider' value (4) but i need assign them a value.
```

Also, the table would have N registers and '@rowcountdivider' would be any integer to 'divide' the rows just like in the example.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* this is what you are looking for? You're almost there with the comment about 'dividing the rows' you just need to add a row number and integer divide it by your `@rowcountdivider` (with a slight adjustment to account for the starting index)

```
SELECT * INTO #Demo FROM (VALUES
 (9,'00001',1),
 (9,'00001',1),
 (9,'00001',1),
 (9,'00001',1),
 (9,'00001',1),
 (9,'00002',1),
 (9,'00003',1),
 (9,'00003',1),
 (9,'00003',1)
 ) A (iStore,vCode,iQty);


DECLARE @rowcountdivider INT = 4;
SELECT 
    iStore
    ,vCode
    ,iQty
    ,((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY vCode) - 1) / @rowcountdivider) + 1 MasterCounter 
FROM #Demo;

iStore      vCode iQty        MasterCounter
----------- ----- ----------- --------------------
9           00001 1           1
9           00001 1           1
9           00001 1           1
9           00001 1           1
9           00001 1           2
9           00002 1           2
9           00003 1           2
9           00003 1           2
9           00003 1           3
```

Comment: Yeah, this is what i'm looking for!! Thank you!